# Is "Negative Repercussion" a correct collocation?

Tags: collocations

Can I use the word "Negative" before the word "Repercussion? For example:

> If they do not take such measures, there may well be a negative
>   repercussion in terms of support for the whole process in some
>   nationalist and republican communities.

Comment: @Lambie It's only *Republican* if referring to a political party (the one in the US in particular). Otherwise, it's just a [regular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/republican) noun and adjective.

Comment: @Lambie The lowercase version certainly does exist. It's in the dictionary, as I provided a link to. Here's [another link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/republican)—this time to Oxford Dictionaries. It makes it clear that the capitalized version is mostly a US thing; otherwise, the word is in lowercase. That's two of the main dictionaries that describe its meaning and use. And nationalism is far from something that's US only. The two things go together in other countries that don't have actual parties of those names.

Comment: @Lambie It could be any country. I've heard American Republicans say that they are democratic and believe in democracy. And I've heard American Democrats say that they are republican (although not as often). The punctuation makes a difference. To say that the word *must* be capitalized (as you did on your first comment) is too broad. It depends on the context.

Comment: @Lambie Of course it can be any country. Otherwise, you are denying the word as it's defined in the English language. Maybe *you* never use it that way, but other people certainly do.

Comment: nationalist and republican could be referring to Ireland, too but not every country has republicans, with a small r. These are not terms for just any country. And I most definitely did not say: **must be capitalized**. I said something slightly different which I no longer recall. And please do not cite dictionaries at me for baby stuff.